# Access model attributes in Laravel update query

Tags: laravel, laravel-9, laravel-query-builder

I have an UPDATE query that I'm struggling with, basically want to access its column during update.

I have a `users` table (with existing data) with a column `address` where a string value is added. To make things cleaner I created a separate table `locations` to store all the addresses and set up `foreignId('location_id')` on the `users` table.

`locations` table is then filled by getting unique `address` values from `users` table.

Now I need to update the `location_id` of existing users.

**This is what I tried:**

```
$locations = Location::get();  // only about 100 results are there

User::query()
    ->whereNotNull('address')
    ->update([
        'location_id' => $locations->firstWhere('street', DB::raw('address'))->id
    ]);
```

But the above query is not updating the column "location_id" on users table.

**Model Relationships**

```
// On Location Model
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\User::class);
}

// On User model
public function location()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Location::class);
}
```

Comment: How many field are you trying to update? and the `->id` belongs to where?

Comment: @IbrahimHammed I'm trying to update only one column `location_id` on users table. `->id` is the `id` of the `locations` table. The query should be updating column `location_id` of all users that have `address` field not null.

Comment: Can you share the relationship status between them?

Comment: @Navid -  I've updated the question body, please have a look at the relationships.

Answer (score 0):

You issue is that DB::raw('address') probably does not return anything so my suggestion is to update the whole query.

```
$locations = Location::all();

User::whereNotNull('address')->each(function($user){
   $locations = $locations->where('name', $user->address)->pluck('id');
   $user->attach($locations);
})
```

The above query will get all the locations first, then we get all the users who have an address and for each of those users we first find all the locations with that address, get the ids of those locations, add attach those locations to the user.

Comment: If there are 1000 users, this query will be called 1000 times. Not very performance optimised. I am  looking to do the same in a single MySQL query.